# Not able to build dual boot in separated hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, bios

I am trying to install a Linux distro in dual boot with an already installed Windows OS, in separated hard drives (each one in a different SSD). Anyway, I am having some troubles with it, which I am not able to fix. The problem comes with the booting system.

At this moment, I already installed in the new SSD drive the following distros: Elementary OS, Deepin OS, Solus OS, Ubuntu. Anyway, when I access the BIOS, it does not detect both drives. If I want to run Linux, I need to manually disconnect the SATA wire of the other SSD, so that only one SSD is connected. After that, if I reconnect the wire to the disconnected SSD, the PC will always boot Linux, so that if I want to run Windows, I need to disconnect the SSD containing Linux, and after that, Windows will be always launched. Both Linux and Windows detect the two SSD drives (Linux from terminal, Windows from disk management).

Moreover, when I installed Solus in the SSD, the BIOS was detecting both systems, so that I could launch any of the OS just by changing the boot priority from the BIOS. That just happened with Solus.

Which could be the solution so that I can have a booting selection when turning on the PC? This is how the BIOS configuration for Boot priority looks like
[image: Bios Boot priority]

Comment: What bootloader are you using? You need to get `grub` or some other bootloader on the drive that you are booting. In grub you can have the different HDs with whatever OS you like.

Comment: But do I need to install separately the bootloader in the Linux distro? Isn't it included already? @user1794469

Comment: This really sounds like a UEFI boot issue

Comment: I've heard about that in many posts, and I'm pretty sure it has to do with it. Anyway, what should I do? As far as I'm concerced, windows is configured to boot in UEFI mode, so the linux distro should be so? How? @couling

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what's happening is that your BIOS is choosing just one EFI boot partition to read.  Each operating system should have its own entries in this special partition.  This should be a small partion < 600mb?

Your BIOS will only be able to boot from one form (usually).  So firstly make sure your linuix is all setup to use EFI boot NOT legacy.  It might be bad news if linux is installed using legacy as you might need to re-install.

The easiest thing to try is just to copy files between your two UEFI partitions.  The windows files will be in a completely different directory to the linux files so they should hapily co-exist on the same partition.  From memory windows doesn't make accessing this easy, so maybe try under linux.

Again from memory, under linux your current EFI partition is usually mounted to `/boot/efi`.  So you would need to mount your windows EFI partition and copy from `/boot/efi/`.

Then boot from your windows disk.

Comment: I've read that some linux distros allow booting in UEFI mode while others doesn't. Could it be the reason why Solus is getting detected by the BIOS and the other 3 mentioned distros no?

Comment: It might be, it might also be that Solus managed to put its EFI files on the right partition.  Usually it's not possible to have different boot mechanisms on the same disk.  EFI needs GPT partitioning.